# Can't able to parse the JSONObject from Object type in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a field **apiResponse** of **Object** type in java. This field is the response of external api which I am calling. I have to convert this field into **JSONObject**. But I am getting the following exception:

```
nested exception is org.json.JSONException: Expected a ':' after a key at 12 [character 13 line 1]] with root cause
```

Following is my code and example apiResponse field:

```
Object apiResponse = externalClient.getDetailsResponse();
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(apiResponse.toString());
```

My sample apiResponse will look like:

```
  {
    "productId": "1234",
    "name": "ProductName",
    "quantity": 1,
    "productAttributes": [
      {
        "color": "Red",
        "size": "XL",
        "externalColors": "Blue pink"
      },
      {
        "color": "Red",
        "size": "XL",
        "externalColors": "Blue pink"
      }
    ]
}
```

This response is not stable, it has sometimes array of objects, objects of objects and nested arrays. So I wanted to combinely convert this into JSONObject. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parsing the JSON looks fine. You should validate that `apiResponse.toString()` really returns the above JSON and not something else.

Comment: " Expected a ':' after a key" indicates that `apiResponse.toString()` is _not_ returning wellformed json as you might expect.

Comment: Yes, ```apiResponse.toString()``` is not parsing properly. I have fixed this by parsing using Gson